# RegEx for Strings like this in java: "stack overflow is awesome (space)(space)(space)(space) 200.00 (space)(space)"

Tags: java, regex

RegEx for Strings like this in Java :

```
"stack overflow is awesome      200.00   "
```

I want to extract only initial words(only `stack overflow is awesome`) without trailing spaces

I have tried this :

```
(^[\w\s]+ ?)([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,2}?)\s{2,}$
```

but result I'm getting is

```
"stack overflow is awesome     "
```

I just want `stack overflow is awesome`

Comment: *without trailing spaces* - `200` is not a trailing space

Comment: Please improve your question by explaining what language you are using, what you have tried, etc.

Comment: `[a-z]+(?: [a-z]+)*`?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please provide me a solution.

Comment: You need to rephrase your question. There are no trailing spaces in your result. The `200.00` after the collection of whitespace means it isn't trailing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^([\\s\\w]+\\w)(?=\\s)
```

See it [live](https://ideone.com/Kdfx3s)

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank you for your answer. Can you please tell how to access 200.00 now?

Comment: @Pralhad correct me if i'm wrong but, you want just to remove multiple spaces from the input, don't you?

Comment: @Thomas...Yes multiple spaces I wanted to remove and create 2 groups one with words and other with decimal number. My decimal number regex was fine earlier now i guess it needs modification.

Comment: @Thomas...I did this : ^([\s\w]+\w)(\s)+([0-9]+\.[0-9]{1,2}?)\s{2,}$ It works perfect... Thank you for your help....

Comment: @Pralhad [see this, it would be much more useful](https://ideone.com/Kdfx3s) (and don't forget to mark answer as accepted it it helped you)

Answer (score 0):

```
Split the input string based on 2 or more spaces.

String input="stack overflow is awesome     200.00   ";
String str[] = input.split("\\s{2,}");
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(str));
```

output:

[stack overflow is awesome, 200.00]